# Предложение построено верно?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Верно ли построено предложение? Не слишком ли тяжеловесно?

> В 1968 г. занял первое место среди участников всех возрастов в
> номинации «Стрельба из малокалиберной винтовки» на районных
> соревнованиях ДОСААФ по пулевой стрельбе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первое. При таком порядке слов возникает ощущение, что "кусок" после слов "в номинации" («Стрельба из малокалиберной винтовки» на районных соревнованиях ДОСААФ по пулевой стрельбе) является собственно названием этой номинации. А это не так.

Второе. Книжное слово [*номинация*](http://www.endic.ru/enc_big/Nominacija-41152.html) используется "при присуждении почетных наград, званий и т. п. на различных фестивалях, конкурсах (обычно в области искусства)".

Третье. Вместо номинации лучше использовать слова *разряд, класс, группа.*
А можно вообще их не использовать, избавиться от кавычек и построить длинное предложение по такой схеме:
когда? — на чем? — среди кого? — (занял первое место) — в чем?

**В 1968 году на районных соревнованиях ДОСААФ по пулевой стрельбе среди участников всех возрастов занял первое место в стрельбе из малокалиберной винтовки.**

Можно использовать скобки:
**В 1968 году на районных соревнованиях ДОСААФ по пулевой стрельбе занял первое место в стрельбе из малокалиберной винтовки (среди участников всех возрастов).**